# Does text contain date format?

Tags: java, string, date, kotlin

Suppose I have this text:

```
how are you? ok, I'm fine and how are you 08-01-20. Nice.
```

How to check if it contains substring in a  specific format? In this case this is a date format: `dd-MM-yy`

```
 how are you? ok, I'm fine and how are you 08-01-20. Nice.
```

This case must return `08-01-20`.

But this text:

```
 how are you? ok, I'm fine and how are you 18:01:21. Nice.
```

must return **null**.

So I need method that return `08-01-20` in first case and return **null** in second case.

Comment: so... any questions?

Comment: have you tried using Regular Expressions ?

Comment: you should add the whatever you've tried and ask... People SHOULD not use stackoverflow as a task agent thing

Comment: *"In this case this is a date format: `dd-MM-yy`"* Really? I think it's `MM-dd-yy`. No, it's `yy-MM-dd`. --- Please realize that `08-01-20` can be `8 Jan 2020`, or `Aug 1 2020`, or `2008 Jan 20`. All are valid dates.

Comment: @Andreas I know about this. But I parse text with fix date format "dd-MM-yy"

Comment: @a_subscriber Then you should have made that clearer in the question.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself. *"must return `true`"* and *"must return `false`"* ***vs*** *"return `08-01-20`"* and *"return `null`"*. Please **edit** the question to clarify it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use match with regex [`.*?\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}.*`](https://regex101.com/r/F2Czdb/1) like so :

```
".*?\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}.*".toRegex().matches(str)
```

---

**Edit**

After OP edit, You can extract the date with the previews regex, then use a formatter to check if the date is valid or not, if yes return it, else return null :

```
fun check(str: String): LocalDate? {
    var formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yy");
    var v = str.replace(".*?(\\b\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\b).*".toRegex(), "$1");
    try{
        return LocalDate.parse(v, formatter);
    }catch(e: DateTimeParseException) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Check [kotlin demo](https://pl.kotl.in/cmPFHVEEZ)

Or if you want to get the same value and not a LocalDate you can return the extracted date as a String like so :

```
fun check(str: String): String? {
    var formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yy");
    var v = str.replace(".*?(\\b\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\b).*".toRegex(), "$1");
    try{
        LocalDate.parse(v, formatter);
        return v;
    }catch(e: DateTimeParseException) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note: in the second part I changed the regex and I used boundaries to avoid some case like [`321-12-4321`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59734803/does-text-contain-date-format#comment105623618_59734861)

**Edit**

@Andreas put a good point in comment, so if you have many dates with that format, and at least one of them is valid, in this case you have to loop over all the matches and check one by one like so :

```
fun check(str: String): LocalDate? {
    var formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yy")
    val regex = Regex("\\b\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\b")

    for (match in regex.findAll(str)) {
        try{
            return LocalDate.parse(match.value, formatter);
        }catch(e: DateTimeParseException) { }
    }
    return null
}
```

This will return the first valid date in your date

Comment: That would match `99-99-99`, which is not a date string. It would also match `111-11-1111`, which is certainly not a date string.

Comment: *Curious:* Why are you escaping `-`? It is only a special character inside a `[X]` character class.

Comment: @Andreas about the second comment I agree with you, about the first one read this https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59734803/1, the OP said it should return true or false, after that I don't see his edit, I will fix that part as well

Comment: 1) You forgot to remove the escaping of `-` in the code. --- 2) I don't see that you fixed anything regarding the question change where OP wants `08-01-20` or `null` returned, instead of `true`/`false`.

Comment: @Andreas check now ;)

Comment: Do you truly believe that input `"321-12-4321"` should return `21 Dec 2043`? --- Do you also believe that input `"a 99-99-99 b 01-02-03 c"` should return `null`, not `1 Feb 2003`?

Comment: @Andreas for the first part we can use boundaries, for the second, the OP assume that he has only one format of date No?

Comment: *"we can use boundaries"* Then show it in the answer. --- *"OP assume that he has only one format of date"* Don't see any such assumption. Could as easily be that OP just want the first one. Doesn't change the fact that `99-99-99` is not a date format, and hence don't count.

Comment: @Andreas I add that in my answer, and about the `99-99-99` it is not a valid date, so it doesn't pass

Comment: But in your code the invalid `99-99-99` text prevents finding the later valid `01-02-03` text. Using a `find()` loop with a regex without `.*` would allow finding the valid text.

Comment: @Andreas the OP said *How to check if it contains substring in a specific format?* what I understand is that he has only one format like that, else the OP should mention this in his answer, else it can be difficult to know what the OP want exactly

Comment: Title *"Does text contain ..."* and question text *"How to check if it contains ..."* are both from earlier version of question wanting `true`/`false` result. --- Anyway, does the text `"a 99-99-99 b 01-02-03 c"` contain a date format, aka a substring in the `dd-MM-yy` format? Yes aka `true` aka date `1 Feb 2003`. Your code says "No" aka `null`. Conclusion: Your code is flawed, according to any reading of the question.

Comment: @Andreas what about now?

Comment: Better, so down-vote removed, but I would likely have expected a good solution to return the first valid date value, not the last. --- Why is `formatter` a `var`, not a `val`?

Comment: @Andreas to be honest I don't code in kotlin before, so I just based on some questions here and there to create that piece of code, I will try to improve it when I back at home 

Comment: I don't code in Kotlin at all, which is why I haven't answered myself. Can still read it enough to see that your earlier attempts were slightly flawed. Good job getting it fixed. 